# Extend AudioWorkletProcessor in wasm-bindgen?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, audio-worklet

The docs on how to use existing javascript web systems within a `rust -> wasm` flow using wasm-bindgen are pretty straight-forward.  In short:

1. List the needed features as dependencies

```
// cargo.toml

[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3.4"
features = [
  'AudioContext',
  'OscillatorNode'
]
```

2. Access through web_sys, and treat them as normal from there.

```
// lib.rs

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl FmOsc {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Result<FmOsc, JsValue> {
        let ctx = web_sys::AudioContext::new()?;
        let primary = ctx.create_oscillator()?;
        let fm_osc = ctx.create_oscillator()?;
```

Link to [full example](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/web-audio.html)

---

While this approach works for most web systems, it is not so simple for ones which require you to extend a class.  In this case I'm trying to use the [AudioWorkletProccessor from `wasm-bindgen`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.AudioWorkletProcessor.html)

In standard usage, you are supposed to extend the `AudioWorkletProcessor` class, then register it. [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_AudioWorklet#Basic_code_framework)

---

How can I approach this problem?  First I need to extend `AudioWorkletProcessor` in Rust (which doesn't do normal classes and inheritance), overriding its `process()` function.  Then I need to make sure `registerProcessor()` is injected into my rust space.

---

EDIT: [WASM docs on extends](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-js-imports/extends.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do that on the JavaScript side. `wasm-bindgen` does not support extending imported classes and re-exporting them to JavaScript; however, they do want to support it eventually and there is an [issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/210) to track it, and a related [RFC](https://github.com/rustwasm/rfcs/pull/11).